# In Carcassonne, what is the point of a Bridge in the expansion set?

Tags: carcassonne

I understand how to use the Bridges (sort of), but I don't understand the strategy/purpose. In almost every expansion set the special rules or powers of the pieces makes sense to me but why would I play a bridge piece? If you are playing with the King set I understand there is a bonus for the longest road but other than that, what is the point of a bridge?

Answer (score 11):

**Their primary purpose of bridges is to be able to play a tile that you normally could not because of a road.**

You have more options to finish a construction, sabotaging with roads/farms becomes significantly harder.

Second, bridges strongly affect farms. As Nick already pointed out, farms turn out to be massively larger. It's not at all uncommon to have a single, huge farmland that spans the entire map, minus the tiny farms at the edges sealed off by towns obviously.

On the other hand, invading an already occupied farmland becomes a lot easier than before.

For example (assuming only base set + first expansion), without bridges, the only way to cross a street in order to invade a farm was with the cloister + single road tile. For that purpose, the Bridges & Castles expansion not only adds bridges, but also several tiles with broken roads to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: Interestingly I've got the official carcossonne on an Android device and farms don't continue under the bridge on there...

Comment: @Ian That's a bug or a wrongly implemented rule though. I have that expansion at home, and the rules explicitly state that bridges do not split farms.

Answer (score 4):

The bridges help to significantly expand farmland, as farms *continue underneath the bridges*.  Using them, you can make really quite massive farms, which means a truck load of points at game end.